# One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, health-analyzer

Hello I am having the following error , and even after checking on forums and googling about it I haven't been able to find the solution to this error. The health report has the option Repair Automatically, which doesn't work. Her is the full error :

Title: 
    One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly.

Severity : 
    1 - Error
Category
    Availability

Explanation :

The following services are managed by SharePoint, but their running state does not match what SharePoint expects: .  This can happen if a service crashes or if an administrator starts or stops a service using a non-SharePoint interface.  If SharePoint-managed services do not match their expected running state, SharePoint will be unable to correctly distribute work to the service.

Remedy : To stop or start a service managed by SharePoint, use the SharePoint service management interface in the SharePoint Central Administration Site.  If a service has crashed, restart the service manually on the affected servers by running "net start [service name]" from a command prompt. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142683".

Failing Servers:     SERVER111

Failing Services     :SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)

Comment: Well, did you reset sptimerv4 outside central administration? Was this on farm which is part of NLB?

Comment: Yes I stopped it and started it back again. Error doesn't go away.

Comment: Well, the whole point of this error is to give you warning to NOT stop/start sptimerv4 outside CA, like e.g. via PowerShell Restart-Service cmdlet. Check with Get-Service sptimerv4 if it's running. If it does (status should be running), unless something is wrong with SPTimer Jobs inside farm, everything should be fine.

Comment: IT is currently running though, but the error persist showing up on Health Report. That's what I don't understand. I press repair automatically button. I reanalyze and still the error is there.

Comment: how many servers do you have? check on all of them that the timer service is running

Comment: Yes it tried it in all of them. Mostly I was concentrated only on the server mentioned : 

Failing Servers: SERVER111

Comment: I'm with you @el94.  It's not so much what caused the error message as it is that it WON'T GO AWAY after the actual error is resolved.  I'm having this on our SP13 intranet, too, and it drives me bonkers!  If the error is resolved--checked and SPTimerV4 IS running on all relevant servers--WHY does the error MESSAGE persist?

Comment: I have no idea. The good news that I woke up one day and it was not there. I did nothing about it. I hope you have the same luck :)